# XML View Event Handler Helper

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use a helper class to invoke a method in xml view as detailed in documentation
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe

```
<Button text="Press Me" press="ZUI5.ZTESTAPP.TestClass.handlePress.call($controller, 'Hello World')"/>
```

However the object does not get resolved in jQuery.sap.getObject (returns undefined).

Here is the helper class code

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/base/Object"], 
    function (Object) {
    "use strict";
    var o =  Object.extend("ZUI5.ZTESTAPP.TestClass", {
        constructor: function(){

        },
        initalize: function(oView){
            this._view = oView;
        },
        handlePress: function(oEvent){
            debugger;
            //alert('Message Set');
        }   
    });
    return o;
    });
```

Comment: What is the UI5 version being used in your app?

Comment: UI5 Version "1.44.45"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in version 1.44.x

Based on the documentation it seems to be introduced in version 1.56 only.

Compare the following documentations

[1.56.x - Handling Events in XML Views](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.56.4/#/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe)

[1.54.x - Handling Events in XML Views](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.4/#/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe)